# Shipping address gets missing after page refresh magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-address

I have tried the below link and some github links 
[Shipping Address Missing on Payment Page Refresh](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148454/shipping-address-missing-on-payment-page-refresh)

When i refresh the page in second step billing address gets empty only country will be visible. 
Anyone suggest what is causing for this, I dig out more with no success.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by Enable the persistent shoppingcart. **Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Persistent Shopping Cart -> Enable Persistence**

Please override the **magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js**

**Comment this code:-**

```
 /**
 * Invalidate Cache By Close Cookie Session
 */

invalidateCacheByCloseCookieSession = function () {
    if (!$.cookieStorage.isSet('mage-cache-sessid')) {
        $.cookieStorage.set('mage-cache-sessid', true);
        storage.removeAll();
    }
};
```

**Add new code :-**

```
 /**
 * Invalidate Cache By Close Cookie Session
 */

invalidateCacheByCloseCookieSession = function () {
    if (!$.mage.cookies.get('mage-cache-sessid')) {
        $.mage.cookies.set('mage-cache-sessid', true);
         storage.removeAll();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by disabling the persistent shoppingcart. `Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Persistent Shopping Cart -> Enable Persistence`

I found it by debugging this Observer: `magento/module-persistent/Observer/CheckExpirePersistentQuoteObserver.php`. This observer is triggered by `controller_action_predispatch`. In this file is are a few checks and if they pass they will expire the quote which will also remove `mage-cache-sessid` cookie. This results in triggering this function:

```
 /**
     * Invalidate Cache By Close Cookie Session
     */
    invalidateCacheByCloseCookieSession = function () {
        if (!$.cookieStorage.isSet('mage-cache-sessid')) {
            $.cookieStorage.set('mage-cache-sessid', true);
            storage.removeAll();
        }
    };
```

in the `magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js` file. Here the `storage.removeAll();` will empty the localstorage.

If you don't want to disable persistent shopping cart, you need take a look at the checks in the Observer: `magento/module-persistent/Observer/CheckExpirePersistentQuoteObserver.php`.

```
if ($this->_persistentData->isEnabled() &&
    !$this->_persistentSession->isPersistent() &&
    !$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn() &&
    $this->_checkoutSession->getQuoteId() &&
    !$observer->getControllerAction() instanceof \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage
    // persistent session does not expire on onepage checkout page to not spoil customer group id
    ) {
        $instance = $instance;
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('persistent_session_expired');
        $this->quoteManager->expire();
        $this->_customerSession->setCustomerId(null)->setCustomerGroupId(null);
    }
```

With `!$observer->getControllerAction() instanceof \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage` they try to prevent to lose the checkout data. But in my case I use custom modules like: PostNL which had their own controller actions in the checkout, so this check would pass and the localstorage was cleared.

PS. There is allready an upcoming fix: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/bcffc4161e4960713922506870e1a4b711c5ca9e#diff-ee3a4dc8a625074b5313aa7d915944fd where the check is based on the requestUri. A side note is that if you leave the checkout page the localstorage is also cleared.